# Validar una cadena solo con las letras a y b, y que contenga al menos un espacio

Tags: java

Hola comunidad de StackOverflow, les comento que se tiene que validar una cadena ingresada desde el teclado que solo debe contener las letras a y b y tener al menos un espacio. Con el código que tengo hasta ahora ya no hay problema con cadenas de tipo "abbaab abba", el problema es que también valida las cadenas que no tienen espacio, ¿qué tengo que agregar para que ya no valide las cadenas que no tienen espacio?`

```
Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);

String cadena = entrada.nextLine();

Pattern rango = Pattern.compile("[^A-Ba-b ]");

Matcher cadenaValida = rango.matcher(cadena);

    if (!cadenaValida.find()) 
        System.out.println("La cadena que ingresaste es valida");

    else
        System.out.println("La cadena no es valida");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

creo que con el siguiente código lo consigues:

```
Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);

String cadena = entrada.nextLine();

Pattern rango = Pattern.compile("([a|b]*\\s[a|b]*)*");

Matcher cadenaValida = rango.matcher(cadena);

if (cadenaValida.matches()) {
    System.out.println("La cadena que ingresaste es valida");
} else {
    System.out.println("La cadena no es valida");
}
```

Ten en cuenta que debes usar matches en lugar de find, para evitar que solo casen subcadenas. El \s indica el carácter espacio

Comment: Yo si arreglas que cuando le pasamos una cadena vacía también la da como buena y explicas un poco en que consiste tu expresion regular te puntuo en positivo.

Comment: Resolviste mi duda, muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo de contestar, y si como dice el usuario Diego L o L, también valida cadenas vacías, pero ese no es problema por ahora. Gracias de verdad

Comment: Para que de por buena la cadena vacía, abría que poner la siguiente expresión regular: Pattern rango = Pattern.compile("[a|b|\\s]*"); . La explicación a esta expresión regular es la siguiente: El carácter "|" funciona como un OR, con lo cual cualquier cadena que contenga la letra "a", o la letra "b" o el carácter " " (el espacio es \\s) valdría. Luego el carácter "*" indica 0 ó más repeticiones, con lo que ya tiene cabida la cadena vacía. Si hubiera algún carácter, tendría que ser a, b o el espacio

Answer (score 0):

boolean. boolean found = matcher.find();
String cadenaConResultado = (found) ? "La cadena que ingresaste es válida" : "La cadena NO es válida";

Comment: Es lo que yo pienso

Comment: Hola Maria. Bienvenida al sitio. Me temo que esta respuesta no puede considerarse de calidad; mas parece un comentario. Tal vez deberías pasarte por [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). :-)

Comment: Gracias por tomarte el tiempo de contestar a mi pregunta, y si quizás podría hacer uso de un booleano, pero tendría que cambiar gran parte de mi código, y me tomaría mas tiempo, y precisamente eso es lo que no tengo, igual muchas gracias por contestar.